# The command ' xx ' returned a non-zero code: 1

Tags: python, docker, pip, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to get to run the facerecogition from (https://github.com/jamct/facerec) on my raspberry pi 3. Therefore the by runs with the newest version of Raspbian Stretch.

I am running:

```
docker build -t facerec:latest .
```

The log is:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  92.16kB
Step 1/8 : FROM resin/raspberry-pi-python:3
3: Pulling from resin/raspberry-pi-python
4dd85375138c: Pull complete
ee3eb420bc0e: Pull complete

.
.
.

Setting up zip (3.0-8) ...
Setting up dh-python (1.20141111-2) ...
Setting up python3 (3.4.2-2) ...
Setting up python3-dev (3.4.2-2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-18+deb8u10) ...
Removing intermediate container 547f850540e3
 ---> f91765949603
Step 5/8 : RUN python3 -m ensurepip --upgrade && pip3 install --upgrade picamera[array] dlib
 ---> Running in 5a803961b75d
Looking in links: /tmp/tmp7kn7e8fp
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (39.1.0)
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (10.0.1)
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Collecting picamera[array]
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/79/c4/80afe871d82ab1d5c9d8f0c0258228a8a0ed96db07a78ef17e7fba12fda8/picamera-1.13.tar.gz (143kB)
Collecting dlib
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/63/92/05c3b98636661cb80d190a5a777dd94effcc14c0f6893222e5ca81e74fbc/dlib-19.19.0.tar.gz (3.2MB)
Collecting numpy (from picamera[array])
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/31/0a/5df350c29a06835d534a6c4f5681075304da38d85f1c69e5226a635a67ce/numpy-1.18.0.zip (5.4MB)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Cython>=0.29.13 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Cython>=0.29.13
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 19.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
The command '/bin/sh -c python3 -m ensurepip --upgrade && pip3 install --upgrade picamera[array] dlib' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

My pip version is:

```
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```

... but I updated with

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

and it tells me this is the newest version.

I guess, its the last entry in the log:

```
The command '/bin/sh -c python3 -m ensurepip --upgrade && pip3 install --upgrade picamera[array] dlib' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I tried to fix the issue with google but since I am very new in working with raspberry pi and docker I would be very thankful if anybody can help.

If anybody needs the full log: https://www.codepile.net/pile/P4xNWyoe (hope it works, never used it)

Cheers

Comment: `picamera[array]` appears wrong. I'm unfamiliar with the library but think this should be just `picamera`

Comment: You can try splitting that line to determine which command is falling: i.e. `RUN python3 -m ensurepip --upgrade` then `RUN pip3 install --upgrade picamera[array] dlib`

Comment: Hmmm. Have a look at this (https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.12/install.html) too. `picamera[array]` is valid.

Comment: Thanks for the hints.

If I seperately RUN `pip3 install --upgrade picamera[array] dlib` it works but if I retry to build the docker image I recieive the same error message.

If I `RUN python3 -m ensurepip --upgrade` it says `/usr/bin/python3: No module named ensurepip`. 

So I guess there is sth wrong pip, ensurepip or python.  I tryed update with 

`sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-pip`

But it tells me I have the newest version of pip (9.0.1-2+rpt2), which I guess is not the newest one.

And I tried the same with Raspbian Buster and its the same problem.

Comment: btw. version of python is 3.5.3

Comment: and with sudo `python3 get-pip.py` it tells me I have installed version 19.3.1

Comment: Pulled out a Pi to try to repro this for you.

Comment: The issue is the `Cython` dependency. The issue has been reported ([link](https://github.com/jamct/facerec/issues/6))

Comment: Curiously, I'm able to install `Cython==0.29.14` in that image so it's one of the transitive dependencies. I'm out of puff on this now. Good luck.

Comment: Curiously, after being able to install `Cython==0.29.14`, trying to install `numpy` (1.18.1) errors with `No matching distribution found for Cython>=0.29.14` which is confusing|weird.

Comment: Thank you for this effort @DazWilkin! How is that possible that Docker does not recognize the correct versions of installed software. There is pip which is installed in version `pip 19.3.1` and Docker tells me I am using `pip 10.0.1` and it also seem to be confusing with `Cython`.